# ASP.NET MVC vs Angularjs com WEBAPI

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, mvc, ddd

Em um projeto web(tipo um "pequeno" ERP, rs) onde algumas empresas iriam administrar suas filiais podendo existir vários usuários conectados, o que seria melhor em questão de performance e desempenho (sei que cada caso é um caso, mas no geral) na opinião de vocês o que seria melhor:
ASP.NET MVC ou Angularjs com WEBAPI? nos dois casos a arquitetura seria DDD com EF e dapper. Obrigado.

Comment: Esta pergunta não tem uma resposta final, pois há muitos fatores a se levar em consideração e acho que por isso alguém tenha votado com -1. Porém, com um pouco de pesquisa você consegue encontrar opniões para te ajudar nesses primeiros passos. Esta pergunta: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23076670/asp-net-mvc-5-vs-angularjs-asp-net-webapi, foi fechada pelo mesmo motivo (muito subjetiva) mas tem algumas respostas bem relevantes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opa, tudo bem?
Essa é uma questão bastante abstrata, mas acho que este link pode lhe ajudar:
https://www.quora.com/What-should-I-choose-Angular-js-or-NET-MVC-Which-language-has-better-career-prospects

Se for levar em consideração apenas a performance, AngularJs, à grosso modo, terá um melhor desempenho por ser um framework javascript e rodar no navegador. Mas isso pode mudar facilmente caso as requisições que a camada apresentação fizer para a web-api sejam lentas, pois a performance acabará se equivalendo e você não terá ganho algum no uso do AngularJs(Caso sua preocupação seja apenas performance). Entretanto há muitos fatores a se considerar, como curva de aprendizagem e segurança. Além do beneficio da performance, a solução do angular, por utilizar uma web-api pode ser uma boa, visto que ela pode ser utilizada por outros sistemas no futuro, como um aplicativo mobile ou uma exposição para outras aplicações consumirem.

Bom, não sei se ajudei, expus um pouco da minha opinião, mas a questão é realmente difícil de ser definida com uma resposta absoluta.

Comment: Olá Murilo, me ajudou sim, realmente tem muita coisa a ser considerado na escolha dessas tecnologias. Vou esperar mais opiniões dos outros colegas, depois marco a resposta ok.

Comment: Melhor não esperar opiniões. Neste site só respostas objetivas são válidas. Por isto sua pergunta está sendo fechada.

Comment: AngularJS 1.x que é a versão stable, é totalmente incopativel com a versão 2, que irá ser lançada (num futuro próximo ou longo), Além de que, se o javascript for mal implementado na view, sua página ficará lenta, já que irá ter um consumo maior de memória ram do navegador...Sobre o MVC, talvez terá maior produtividade, por ter html helpers...Com base na sua pergunta é bem difícil, não sabemos o conhecimento do time, nem o prazo de entrega do projeto

Comment: Não entendi porque alguém votou com -1 para a resposta do Murilo, a meu ver ele respondeu bem (por isso deu um +1). Porém, como comentei   na anteriormente, acho que este tipo de pergunta deveria realmente ser fechada.